# Cannot use System.getProperty

Tags: eclipse, windows, system-properties

I am trying to use `System.getProperty("foo")`, to read some variables in eclipse. Two ways I have tried

1. Specify in the run configuration in environment tab
2. Specicy with -D in eclipse.ini file

I am using windows machine, could anybody help me with this

Comment: Changing the `eclipse.ini` file only affects Eclipse itself. Your applications run in a separate JVM. Where in the Environment tab are you specifying whatever you specified? Maybe include an image?